# How to declare a function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have a function and  i did it in this way

**JS :**

```
function updateInstitution (isValid) {alert('hi')
    if (!isValid) {
        $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity', 'vm.form.institutionForm');
        return false;
    }
    var data = JSON.stringify(vm.institution);
    httpService.put('institutions/' + vm.institution_id, data).then(function (results) {
        if (results && results.data && results.data.details) {
            vm.institution = results.data.details;
            formInstitutionData('profile');
            commonService.showNotification('success', 'Institution Details updated successfully!');
            $('#institutionModal').modal('hide');    
        }   
    });     
} 
}
  vm.updateInstitution = updateInstitution;
```

**Html :**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-blue"  ng-click="vm.updateInstitution(vm.form.institutionForm.$valid)" ng-bind="field.saveText"></button>
```

But i am getting the error as

```
updateInstitution is not defined
```

Can anyone please suggest help.Thanks.

**JS :**

```
    (function () {
  'use strict';

  // Institutions controller
  angular
          .module('institutions')
          .controller('InstitutionsController', InstitutionsController);

  InstitutionsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$window', '$timeout', 'httpService', 'Authentication', 'commonService'];



    function active() {
      httpService.get('institutions/' + vm.institution_id).then(function (results) {
        if (results && results.data && results.data.details) {
          vm.institutionCopyData = angular.copy(results.data.details);
          formInstitutionData('all');
        }
      });
    }

    $scope.editInstitutionModal = function (type) {
      $scope.field = {};
      $scope.showInstitutionModal = false;
      if (type === 'basicedit') {
            $scope.field.field_type = 'edit-institution.form.client';
            $scope.field.formName = 'Edit institution (' + vm.institutionObj.name + ')';
            $scope.field.saveText = 'Update';  
      }
      if(type === 'general'){
            $scope.field.field_type = 'add-general.form.client';
            $scope.field.formName = 'General Info';
            $scope.field.saveText = 'Save';          
      }
      $timeout(function () {
        $scope.showInstitutionModal = true;
        $('#institutionModal').modal('show');
        $scope.$apply();
      }, 10);
    };


    function updateInstitution (isValid) {alert('hi')
        if (!isValid) {
            $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity', 'vm.form.institutionForm');
            return false;
        }
        var data = JSON.stringify(vm.institution);
        httpService.put('institutions/' + vm.institution_id, data).then(function (results) {
            if (results && results.data && results.data.details) {
                vm.institution = results.data.details;
                formInstitutionData('profile');
                commonService.showNotification('success', 'Institution Details updated successfully!');
                $('#institutionModal').modal('hide');    
            }   
        });     
    } 
    }
  }
}());
```

But i am getting the error as

```
updateInstitution is not defined
```

Can anyone please suggest help.Thanks.

But i am getting the error as

```
updateInstitution is not defined
```

Can anyone please suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: Have you defined the "controller as" definition then only can use in this way?

Comment: What about the context of the function definition? Could you maybe create a fiddle with your current state?

Comment: `var updateInstitution = function(isValid) { /* your functions body */ }`

Comment: Can you post your whole directive structure?

Comment: Have you defined `$scope.vm = vm;`?

Comment: You have one extra `}` which gives me an immediate error.

Comment: You are using `Controller as` syntax inside the HTML but still using `$scope` inside the controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should declare the following in your controller:

```
var vm = this;
vm.updateInstitution = updateInstitution;
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code of your directive, or recreate the situation in a fiddle ? This is not enough info for us.

Comment: I also see an extra `}`. Maybe you're closing your controller already before defining the bindables.

Comment: No prob, hope we could help.

Answer (score 0):

you use **$scope.updateInstitution**  instead of **function updateInstitution()** , because communication bridge between html and controller is $scope,
or for use vm.function you defined $scope.vm

Comment: but here i am declaring function in js

Answer (score -1):

```
 $scope.updateInstitution = function(){
     //Your code
  }
```

Comment: do you see the ng-click as vm.updateInstitution how this will call the function ?